# DNAT redirection works but returns with the redirect IP

Tags: iptables, dnat

I'm doing a test that my clients, network 10.101.29.0/24, when try to connect to 192.168.100.100 been redirected to 10.10.10.222.
This part is working, but my problem is on the answer. The answers is arriving is 10.10.10.222 and what I want is the firewall/router change back to 192.168.100.100 before to give back to the client.
This is what I did on my firewall/router:

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -s 10.101.29.0/24 -d 192.168.100.100 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.222

There is just this line, nothing more.

Here my netowrk:

10.101.29.0/24 |-> <-|10.101.29.1,172.16.50.100|-><-|172.16.50.1|-> Servers

I already tried

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -d 10.10.10.222 -j RETURN

and

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -s 10.10.10.222 -d 10.101.29.0/24 -j DNAT --to 192.168.100.100

but nothing works.

Should I load statefull modules?

Best regars.

Comment: Is it possible that your reply returns to your client by different path (omitting your DNAT box)? It is not clear form me from your explanation. Where on your network is 10.10.10.222 attached?

Comment: Hello Tomek. No, the answer always came back through the Linux machine. This iptables/router is the default gateway for 10.101.29.0/24.

Comment: It is default gateway for OUTGOING packets. What about incoming? And again - where is 10.10.10.222 attached?

Comment: Yes, this gateway is for OUTGOING. The 10.10.10.222 is on your DMZ. There are more two gateways. One for the 192.168.100.100 and other for 10.10.10.222. But the return path is knowing for both and always pass through this Linux.

Comment: Provide the outputs of `iptables-save -t nat` and `ip -4 r ls table all`,  and `ip -4 ru ls` commands from NAT box, please.

Comment: Hello Anton Danilov. Here the outputs

Comment: # Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Jun 13 09:00:40 2019
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [4890:621561]
:INPUT ACCEPT [72:16245]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [392:32864]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2073:376312]
-A PREROUTING -s 10.101.29.0/24 -d 192.168.100.100/32 -i eth1 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.222
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Jun 13 09:00:40 2019

Comment: Output of ip -4 r ls table all
default via 172.16.50.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 100 
10.101.29.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.101.29.1 metric 101 
172.16.50.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.103.0.222 metric 100 
broadcast 10.101.29.0 dev eth1 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.101.29.1 
local 10.101.29.1 dev eth1 table local proto kernel scope host src 10.101.29.1 
broadcast 10.101.29.255 dev eth1 table local proto kernel scope link src 10.101.29.1

Comment: broadcast 172.16.50.0 dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope link src 172.16.50.100
local 172.16.50.100 dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope host src 172.16.50.100 
broadcast 172.16.50.255 dev eth0 table local proto kernel scope link src 172.16.50.100 
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1

Comment: Output of ip -4 ru ls
0:      from all lookup local 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default

Answer (score 0):

After Tomek comment I was looking for better this netowrk, I'm knew in this company, and figure out that another router were been used as reponse path.
Becouse of this the client network was receiving a different IP.

Thanks for all help.

Best regards